# Adding ADFS Authentication to Regular Windows 7 login

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-domain, windows-authentication, two-factor-authentication

I have setup a Windows Server 2012 R2 as a Domain Controller and I have also enabled ADFS (Active Directory Federation Services).

I have a Windows 7 client, that joined the previous Domain controller.

How can I enable the ADFS Authentication mechanism (e.g. certificates and/or also Multi-Factor Authentication) in Windows 7 when the end-user tries to login to the domain controller?

Answer (score 0):

ADFS is used to allow access to domain resources from outside the domain.

Multifactor authentication within your domain is independent of ADFS.  Most of the search results about this lead to third party options.

Some of the third party options for multifactor authentication within the domain also include ADFS access using multifactor authentication.

The Windows Server family includes all the parts you need to set up PKI authentication.

To integrate all these parts together into a solution for your organization is the job of a systems architect.